# How do you convert a formula in text form, into it's value in excel?

Tags: excel, text, formula

I have a document which calculates staff's annual leave with a new sheet for each member of staff. There is a main page with all staff listed with certain values that link to each staff's individual sheet.

For example ='Smith, J'!A1.

I need to mass change these values. I don't want to be clicking to each staff's sheet to change each value. I've used a formula to bring up each staff's name based on their first and last name on the main page.

Example ="='" & A1 & ", " & left(B1, 1) & "'!A1"

Then paste it's value to get ='Smith, J'!A1 as text. Clicking on the cell and hitting return results in the correct value but I don't know how to do this for a mass number of cells other than clicking on each cell individually and hitting return.

I would prefer to not use vbs as many staff would view the document and all would have to allow for macros on their own excel.

Comment: Have you tried using ***INDIRECT()*** ??

Comment: I did not!! Thank you that's bloody perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right answer is to use the indirect function:

```
=INDIRECT("'Smith, J'!A1")
```

Comment: You can also use the hyperlink function like this =HYPERLINK("#'Smith, J'!A1", "Smith, J")

Note the # symbol in front of the worksheet name, this is important.